# ReactJS: Saving a value in localStorage with useReducer

Tags: reactjs

Hello I have a problem saving my current theme. Basically I can change the theme normally, but when I update the page it goes back to my light theme.

I can't find a solution to save my state type in `localstorage`.

Code:

```
export default function App() {
  const [theme, setTheme] = usePersistedState('light');
  const toggleTheme = () => {
    setTheme(theme.type === 'light' ? { type: 'dark' } : { type: 'light' });
  };
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={toggleTheme}>a</button>
      </div>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

My hook:

```
    function usePersistedState(key) {
      const getTheme = themeType => () => {
        switch (themeType) {
          case 'dark':
            return darkTheme;
          case 'light':
            return lightTheme;
          default:
            return lightTheme;
        }
      };

      const reducer = (state, action) => {
        // this will run on every state change (on every dispatch call)
        return getTheme(action.type)();
      };

      const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, null, getTheme(key)); // first argument is the reducer function. second argument is the initial state. third argument is an init function (for complex initialization)

      console.log(state);
        useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('theme', JSON.stringify(state.type));
  }, [key, state]);
```

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to implementing a persisted state hook would be to extend the regular `setState` hook with persistence logic "wrapped" around the setter method that `setState` provides.

This added persistence logic would store the most recent state value (provided by client code) to `localStorage`, effectivly synchronizing your persistance layer with the most recent state value set:

```js
function usePersistedState(key, mapper, defaultKey) {

  const [state, setState] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {

    /* Called once on component mount. Load persisted JSON
    once, parse JSON, and apply to the hook's local runtime state */
    const persistKey = localStorage.getItem(key);

    setState(mapper(persistKey || defaultKey));
  }, []);

  const setStateAndPersist = (newKey) => {

    /* Intercept setState, at which point we update local storage on
    the nominated key to reflect the most recent state value set by 
    client code */
    localStorage.setItem(key, newKey);

    setState(mapper(newKey));
  }

  /* Expose theme state, and intercepted setter function */
  return [state, setStateAndPersist];
}
```

The `useEffect` hook is also used to load any previously persisted state for the `key`, into the `usePersistedState` hooks local state. Note that `useEffect` has a `[]` passed as the second argument, which ensure that the effect is only run once (seeing we only want to load persisted state once during the `usePersistedState` hooks lifecycle).

This hook would then require the following changes in your code:

```
const [themeKey, setTheme] = usePersistedState('theme-key', (themeType) => {
 switch (themeType) {
      case 'dark':
        return darkTheme;
      case 'light':
        return lightTheme;
      default:
        return lightTheme;
    }
}, 'light');
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi thanks a lot, but I have a question how would I return my theme object?

I'm in doubt of how to return the theme object pq without returning the object generates an error:
Please make your theme prop a plain object

Comment: Oops thanks for helping, but I still have the same error:
I have two themes:
import {darkTheme, lightTheme} from './themes/index';

I would need to pass them on to my theme provider

Comment: Are you able to post a new question with that error and send me a link to that question? It would be easier for me to help with a bit more context of how your provider fits into the project, etc - thanks!

Comment: Okay, but there is time to open another question, but basically the error is because my state is not an object (an object with my themes).

Comment: My state should return either my dark theme object or my light theme object

Comment: Just extended answer - does that help?

Comment: still has the same problem, for some reason does not enter useState, and is not creating my key on localstorage. basically i need i have a standard theme (light)
if there is no key in the storage it is called, and it is called my function toggleTheme

I switch to my dark theme and save it to storage when I update the page.

Comment: What do you mean by 'it does not enter useState' ?

Comment: sorry useEffect *