# How to get `text` from localStorage having useReducer in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

Currently, I am trying to use `useReducer` with `localStorage` in react.js and have implemented small `Reducer tasks`.

Almost all I have set `tasks` by using localStorage but couldn't access the `text` from it. (and it shows me empty array)

I have set `initialTasks` like this: Don't know what I'm missing here.

[image: Devtools Localstorage Image]

Below are some snippets of my trial code:

1. **ReducerPractice.js**

```
...

import tasksReducer from "./tasksReducer";

const initialTasks = {
  tasks:
    localStorage.getItem("tasks") == null
      ? []
      : JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks")),
};

export default function ReducerPrac() {
  const [{ tasks }, dispatch] = useReducer(
    tasksReducer,
    {
      tasks: [],
    },
    initialTasks
  );

  const tasksId = useRef(0);
  function handleAddTask(text) {
    dispatch({
      type: "added",
      id: tasksId.current + 1,
      text: text,
    });
  }

  function handleChangeTask(text) {
    dispatch({
      type: "changed",
      text: text,
    });
  }

  function handleDeletetask(taskId) {
    dispatch({
      type: "deleted",
      id: taskId,
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(tasks));
  }, [tasks]);

  return (
    <>
      <h3>Reducer todo</h3>
      <AddTask onAddTask={handleAddTask} />
      <br />
      <TaskList
        tasks={tasks}
        onChangeTask={handleChangeTask}
        onDeleteTask={handleDeletetask}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

2. **tasksReducer.js**

```
export default function tasksReducer(tasks, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    
    case "added": {
      return [
        ...tasks,
        { id: action.id, text:  action.text, done: false },
      ];
    }
    case "changed": {
      return tasks.map((t) => {
        if (t.id === action.text.id) {
          return action.text;
        } else {
          return t;
        }
      });
    }
    case "deleted": {
      return tasks.filter((t) => t.id !== action.id);
    }
    default: {
      throw new Error("Unknown dispatched action" + action.type);
    }
  }
}
```

And Also I'm getting this error too:

```
react-dom.development.js:16548 Uncaught TypeError: init is not a function
    at mountReducer (react-dom.development.js:16548:1)
    at Object.useReducer (react-dom.development.js:17682:1)
    at useReducer (react.development.js:1626:1)
    at ReducerPrac (ReducerPrac.js:15:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
```

**Note:** I have searched all over the stack overflow questions listed below but doesn't work for me: (somewhat in 2nd link they also said for `useContext`)

1. [ReactJS: Saving a value in localStorage with useReducer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60243531/reactjs-saving-a-value-in-localstorage-with-usereducer)
2. [How to use localStorage with useReducer hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70231972/how-to-use-localstorage-with-usereducer-hook)

I'd appreciate your help!

PS: One question was is there any need to use `useContext` with `useReducer` & `localStorage` in reactjs.

Answer (score 1):

`useReducer` takes only 2 arguments

```
useReducer(
    tasksReducer,
    initialTasks
  );
```

Comment: yes, I know I actually solved my issue  a while ago :)              1. I replaced those args with two args as you've mentioned. 2. I modified `intialTasks` with this `const initialTasks =
  localStorage.getItem("tasks") == null ? [] : JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks"));` simply so that I could get only array with objects not nested arrays.  *BTW thankyou for your answer*!!